# How do I get a shark to attack me when diving?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I'm trying to finish up some challenges and one of them is to survive a shark attack 10 times.  I somehow managed to get two sharks to attack me but can't really figure out how I did that.  They only seem to want to take a bite of me and run away... but not an actual attack.

**How do I get a shark to attack me when diving?**

Is it totally random how they attack me? Or do I need to provoke them in a certain way before they attack me?  Maybe a certain health level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shark attacks are indeed random.  There doesn't seem to be a sure-fire way to get them to attack you.  I've tried many ways to provoke an attack but could not find any pattern to it:

- Swimming out in the open water.
- Swimming directly at them.
- Swimming up to them from behind.
- Swimming below them.
- Swimming above them.
- Swimming with your back to them.
- Swimming near jellyfish.

No pattern, they'll attack when they feel like it.  Just make yourself an easy target for them and hope that they'll actually attack you and not just take a bite.

If you're trying to complete the Abstergo challenge, it's best to find a school of sharks that are swimming near the diving bell.  Try different diving locations until you find them.  At least if you were unsuccessful getting them to attack you and you're low on health, you could always retreat to the bell to recover your health and oxygen.

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way to do it is to swim with the shark, after he takes a nibble, follow him away. I've been doing that, and using that have gotten it to work most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if its coincidence but i waited until i grabbed a shark's attention and then stopped swimming, faced the shark and repeatedly pressed the B(counter) button as the shark approached. using this method i was able to get the same shark to attack me 4 times within 5 minutes

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I ever tried just sopping in place. That sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious if there was a pattern, so I tested the bite-fight-bite-fight theory. I dived at Blue Hole, where I swam from diving bell to the bow of the wreck (what prankster designed a cartoon lion as a figurehead???) then down to the top of the broken mast to meet the first shark. 
First he bit me and swam away, then he came back and fought me. Rough fight. Used the crossbeam at the top of the wreck to boost back to the diving bell. Once at full health I went back and did it again.

So far I've had 20 fights with that first shark, and I'm averaging two fights before I have to return to the diving bell for air and healing now. Every single time it's the same tho, no matter what side of me the shark is on, whether I'm swimming or drifting, holding down Counter or any other key... The first encounter is always a bite, the second one always a fight. If this pattern breaks, I'll post here, but if I get to 40 fights and the pattern hasn't broken yet, I'm calling it. 
Bizarre observation : although the sharks in the blood cloud between the two halves of the wreck are CLEARLY agitated, the blood cloud you leave behind when you survive a shark attack, seems to have no effect. The cloud dissapates to quickly to stack two clouds from two fights, but that might be an interesting experiment, if someone's in the mood. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a slightly different way which does require you to make trips to air barrels and the divin bell. Go up to a single shark and get its attention. If it simply bites you then follow that same shark around. When it spots you for the second time it will count as a shark attack and you will have to fend it off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get two sharks on you at once to make there be an attack that you can survive with the button mash.  Source: personal experience of doing this method to get the challenge myself

Answer (score 0):

The way to get them to attack is to swim into a school of sharks.

At The Blue Hole diving point, swim to the right of the shipwreck and you will see three sharks in a cloud of red blood as they eat the fish, swim into this red cloud and wait until they attack, worked every time for me and the diving bell is close for when you die and need to come back for more :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to swim along with them without them realizing. When they see you, they atack you and you can fight with the buttons. Doesn't matter where you are or which shark you follow.

Answer (score 0):

an extremely late answer i know, but the best way to get a shark to attack you is to get the sight meter on a shark to the halfway point; gotta make sure the circle blinks. when it does, approach it or let it approach you, does not matter. this will trigger an attack.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroing this but as I am replaying AC:BF atm I wanted to post a fool proof way to do this even if only I search for it at a later date again.

Just replay the dive introduction mission. After the cave you get pulled through by a current just swim a bit forward, just enough for the first shark to notice you. Let him bite you once and wait there. The same shark should attack you again (swimming a bit towards him helps). If he does the main attack, you have to answer with the **Q**uick **T**ime **E**vent. GG one try done (if you succeed). If he bites you again you can try to wait again and then do a QTE if you are fast enough.

If he bites you a third time or you manage to do the QTE, just return to last checkpoint and restart. Guaranteed way to do this challenge easily.